# Restart MySQL in Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, apache, docker, dockerfile

Command:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN service mysql restart
RUN mysql -u root -e "create database test"
```

MySQL fails to restart:

```
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld
 ...done.
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld
 ...fail!
```

The idea is that if I run the image as a container and I restart it there it's fine and it restarts, but not here. I basically wan to create an image that has a DB.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Entrypoint instead of Run

Comment: I am new to docker, can u give me an example plz?

Comment: Why don't you use the official mysql docker image?

Comment: Because I am basically trying to install a CMS, so I need apache mysql and some extensions. I was thinking to use a docker file so I can simply create an image if i want to change the php version or the cms version. Is ther a better way to achive this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dockerfile then you should put all install-operations in RUN and put all executions in the ENTRYPOINT section.

For example in your case you could use this instructions:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server
ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && bash
```

This guide should help you https://ollyxar.com/blog/docker-phpstorm-windows

Comment: If i generate the docker image without an entrypoint i run it like this:
docker run --name example1 -i -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 myimage
(this way i can go to my browser and see apache and interact in the browser )

If I use ENTRYPOINT whenever i try to run the image as a container with the same command, the container automatically dies

how can I run it in the background and still execute a script/command in entrypoint?

Comment: You can use *docker exec -it container_name bash* to login in certain container

Comment: @johnnyshrewd obviously you have to run container before exec